# NoMethodError in Admin::Posts#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, posts

I'm new to rails and i want to implement a Post feature. I also use active admin.
So my idea was to add a new String to my migration file, so i could give the post a theme to distinguish my posts and show a post with theme "xyz" at the site "xyz". But if i try to create a new post it gives me the error:

> undefined method `theme' for #Post:0x000000000f37b2c0  and throws up the error in the post.rb : f.input :theme

My migration file looks like:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
def change
create_table :posts do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.text :body
  t.string :theme

  t.timestamps
end
```

and my post.rb from active admin:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
permit_params :title, :body, :theme, :publisher_id
permit_params :title, :body, :theme, :image
 show do |t|
    attributes_table do
        row :title
        row :body
        row :theme
        row :image do
            post.image? ? image_tag(post.image.url, height: '100') : content_tag(:span, "No photo yet")
        end
    end
end

form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data"} do |f|
    f.inputs do
        f.input :title
        f.input :body
        f.input :theme
        f.input :image, hint: f.post.image? ? image_tag(post.image.url, height: '100') : content_tag(:span, "Upload JPG/PNG/GIF image" )
    end
    f.actions
end
```

and later on i wanted to do something like

```
if posts.theme = xyz do 
 <h1><%= @post.title %></h1>
 <h2> <%= @post.body %></h2>
end
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you run the migration (`rails db:migrate`)?

Comment: @max yes i have, but nothing changed. but yesterday i had also assets:precompile errors. Can this be the problem?

Comment: Check in your database: you have a posts table, but does it have a theme column?

Comment: How do you compare posts(array or relation) with string? (xyz) ???